# What is the meaning of "If nationalism could create a strong and effective insularity....." from the highlighted part in the picture down below?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

[image: screenshot of text]

What is the meaning of:

> “If nationalism could create a strong and effective insularity, deliver on its promise of self-respect, then the hurt it might cause well-meaning whites, or the inner turmoil it caused people like me, would be of little consequence.”

Comment: These words are from Barack Obama. So as is usual with high-level politicians, the words are carefully crafted to mean whatever different people *want* them to mean. What exactly is Obama's "**a strong and effective insularity**", and how does that differ from Trump's aspirations to "**make America great again**"? I think it's really just a natter of (Off-Topic) opinion.

Comment: But at the simplest level, he's saying that he wouldn't object to the concept of nationalism ***if*** it led to a well-integrated society. Ergo, since the US obviously ***isn't*** currently a well-integrated society, my personal assumption is he's saying he ***disapproves*** of "nationalism". Make of that what you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author (Obama) is referring to "black nationalism", approximately as defined here:

[Lexico "black nationalism"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/black_nationalism)
(especially in the US) advocacy of or support for unity and political self-determination for black people, especially in the form of a separate black nation.

See also
[Wikipedia "black nationalism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_nationalism)

The author is saying that *if* such nationalism could effectively separate the black community (create an insularity, the condition of an island), while promoting the self-respect of the black people, *then* it wouldn't be very important if it hurt him or well-meaning white people.